# How to validate, store and execute user rules?

Tags: python, regex, validation, python-3.x

In my application:

- there are users.
- emails come in to the system.
- users can use a web browser to define filter rules for their inbound emails.

Filter rules are of the general form "if field operator value/regex then do action X with parameter Y"

I need to:

1. validate the user rules (which will be created by the user with
   an HTML page of dropdowns and text fields)
2. store the user rules in some appropriate format (maybe as Python
   source?)
3. execute the rules within my Python processing script.

My question is:

is this is a "solved problem"? I want to avoid reinventing the wheel and it sure seems like this or something conceptually very similar must have been done before.  Maybe there's even some sort of open source library or application that already does it.

If it is not a solved problem, can anyone suggest an effective way to validate, store and execute the rules? I'm guessing somehow it makes sense for the rules to be Python statements but I sure as hell don't want to write a language syntax parser.

UPDATE: Although the users will be very technical/likely developers, I still want the entry of rules to be tightly constrained to the general form specified above.  *very* similar to the email rules you probably have in your email client right now. For example "if subject contains "subscribe" then send reply email to fromaddress"

UPDATE 2: The filtering rules will not only be on the email fields but also on other non email stuff, for example, the content of an attachment, or evaluation of a custom field that relates to the email but is not part of the email, generated by my system.

Any input valued.

I'm using Python 3.

Comment: Could you give a few examples of rules? Also, what is your userbase. If it is predominantly programmers, you could simply allow rules to be entered as regexs.

Comment: How about choosing the [sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_%28mail_filtering_language%29) language as your storage for mail filtering rules, and using a library like [`sievelib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sievelib) to read and write them?

Comment: @LukasGraf sieve - interesting I'll check it out, BUT I would say that  the rules will not be constrained only to acting on emails but also more arbitrary rules evaluating for example fields generated by my system that are not part of the email being evaluated. I wonder perhaps sieve is too restrictive if it is primarily for email filtering.

Comment: Well yes, you *were* talking about email filtering in your question!

Comment: @LukasGraf, true, I'll update.  It's a great suggestion though, thanks.

Comment: Write some sort of "plug-in" system where user can code their filters in some simple language, even Python itself.

Comment: Why not take a reverse approach - rather than creating a syntax parser, write your code to translate user rule input into syntactically correct language from the start, e.g. Your own code translates UI dropdown/textbox input saying "if [text box string var] is in the subject line, do Y' to "if bool(re.search, textboxstringvar, subjectlinestring) is True: y".  No need to parse syntax in many cases this way.